# Swift storyboards: split view controller not showing properly on MacOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, xcode-storyboard

I am trying to implement a split view controller using storyboards & swift on MacOS:

[image: xcode screenshot]

For some reason only the right side shows up. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a window size issue. As it is undefined it push the left side out of view. Just place the cursor on the left side and drag to show the left view.

[image: shot]

Hope it helps.

---

**UPDATE:**

It's actually **NOT** a window size issue. It looks like that the *split view controller* push one side out of view by default. Conversely, I was able to view the two panes correctly using the *split view component* inserted into a view controller.

[image: screen]

I'll be checking for information about this issue in the latest WWDC:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=212

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=214

---

**UPDATE 03/11/14:**

After minute 07:00 of the first screencast I got what was going on. Take a look at the screenshot below:

1. Make the ***Split View Controller*** as wide as the main window.
2. Resize the ***Split View Items***.
3. Click on the items with the right most ***Split View Item***, add **Missing Constraints** from the *Pin pop up menu*.

[image: solution]

> It may take few tries before you get it right. I tested it three times and it did work.

Comment: How do i define it so it stops doing that ?

Comment: Missing constraints is not clickable. I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/ObjC_classic/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001093

NSSplitViewDelegate

class SplitViewController: NSSplitViewController{//,NSSplitViewDelegate

[Swift storyboards: split view controller not showing properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705507/swift-storyboards-split-view-controller-not-showing-properly/31492669#31492669)

It was really problem for me as well. Now I got solved this problem in my code.

1.Create a class extended NSSplitViewController. 
2.Set a class created in phase1 as Custom class on your SplitView which you created on StoryBord. 
3.call MySplitView.adjustSubviews() inside viewDidLoad().

```
import Cocoa

class SplitViewController: NSSplitViewController{//,NSSplitViewDelegate
    @IBOutlet weak var MySplitView: NSSplitView!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        MySplitView.adjustSubviews();
    }
    override func splitView(splitView: NSSplitView, constrainMinCoordinate proposedMinimumPosition: CGFloat, ofSubviewAt dividerIndex: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return proposedMinimumPosition + 200
    }
}
```